# How to weigh feature array

Tags: neural-network, feature-scaling, k-nn

I have a feature array of around 4000 elements, extracted from one source. On this array I've extracted 7 more feature from other source and now I basically have a 4007 feature array from each data point. I am trying to classify these data points based on this feature array, basically doing a 1NN with manhattan distance.

However since I am really bad at maths I'm not sure how to weigh this so my 7 elements can actually help in regards to this. It feels like those 4000 elements are way more important and on distance calculation the other 7 are insignificant.

I've also given this input to a Neural Network and i'm wondering if I need to preprocess something there aswell or can I just give it the 4007 elements to the input neurons?

I've done feature-scaling but I guess that is irrelevant to the problem I'm asking.

Comment: With such a high dimension on the feature space, it is worth performing some kind of dimensionality reduction, such as PCA or Non Negative Matrix Factorization... If you consider that these 7 extra features are not relevant to separate the feature space, I'd not add them

Answer (score 0):

The goal of supervised machine learning is automatically learn the features weights to predict target values.

If you have target values, you can fit a machine learning algorithm (e.g., a k-nearest neighbors or a neural networks).

There is no need to pick the weights yourself, the algorithm will do it for you.